# branch point of elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ramification

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $X$ be elliptic curve over algebraic closed field $k$, and $P_0\in X$.

By Hartshorne's Algebraic geometry, linear system $|2P_0|$ define morphism $f:X\to \mathbb{P}^1$such that degree$f=2$.

By Hartshorne, $f$ ramify at $P_0$. But I can't understand, help me.

Comment: While it can be described in terms of the behavior of the sheaf of relative differentials, I've always found the most intuitive description of the ramification locus to be $f^*$ of the branch locus, which is the set of points $x \in \mathbb P^1$ such that equality does *not* hold in the bound $|f^{-1}(x)| \le \deg(f)$. In other words, if $d = \deg (f)$ then the general fiber of $f$ consists of $d$ reduced points; ramification occurs when some of those points "collide."...

Comment: ...In your case, this is saying that $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $P_0$ (when thought of as a rational function), meaning $P_0$ is the unique point mapping to $\infty \in \mathbb P^1$ and at $P_0$ the map locally resembles $z \mapsto z^2$. I should also say that my description of the ramification locus is probably slightly off when $d > 2$, since in that case you can have reduced points in a non-reduced fiber.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you tell me about meaning of terms of the behavior of the sheaf of relative differentials

Comment: For an elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ and $P_0=\infty=[0:1:0]$ the morphism is $[x:y:1]\to [x:1]$ which is ramified at $\infty$ because $x$ has a double pole. $[x:y:1]\to [f(x,y):1]$ is unramified at $P$ iff $f$ has a simple pole or a simple zero at $P$.

Comment: @Ryu There's not a ton to say, just that the sheaf of relative differentials is supported along the ramification locus.